# How do I display a list of files in ExplorerBrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-api-code-pack

I wrote an algorithm that finds files that match a particular criteria. After I obtain these files (`FileInfo` objects), how can I display them in the `ExplorerBrowser` control? I am very new to the Windows API Code Pack.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Treeview` to display them  and then use `ProcessStartInfo` to open such wanted files such that:

```
foreach(FileInfo file in objects)
       {
          treeView1.Nodes.Add(file.FullName);
       }
```

after use `NodeMouseClick` such:

```
 private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
            string args = string.Format("/Select, {0}", treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);

            ProcessStartInfo process= new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", args);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(process);
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this does not answer the question at all.